# use forked version of a gem - rails 3.020 & ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to use this fork of a gem:

https://github.com/hoyaemt/capistrano-syntax-checking

In my gemfile I have:

gem "capistrano-syntax-checking", :git => "git://github.com/hoyaemt/capistrano-syntax-checking.git"

When I run bundle install, I get:

Could not find gem 'capistrano-syntax-checking (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/hoyaemt/capistrano-syntax-checking.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'capistrano-syntax-checking (>= 0) ruby'

I have read a bunch of postings but nothing I try seems to work here. Any ideas?

thanks
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original version is missing the gemspec file.  It may be missing other things but I was able to get the bundler to run.

Add a gemspec file to the root of your fork.  See [here](http://matschaffer.com/2010/12/your-own-gem/) for a simple example and just create capistrano-syntax-checking.gemspec file.